# Anyone using multiple items slider without JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins

I want a plugin to show multiple items a slider ( similar to http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ Please check multiple items demo )

There are many plugins available but all of them using CSS / JS / JQuery. But I want a plugin without using JS / JQuery.

Yes, there are css3 plugins but they are showing 1 item per slide

Many of us need this plugin since in future one of the major site is getting rid of JS / JQuery from their site